# How do you draw a graph based on a formula in MATLAB or Python?

Tags: python, matlab

Recently, I have been trying how to express a simple signal in the form of ambiguity function images, but it didn't work.
So I'm wondering, for any formula, how do you describe it and graph it in MATLAB or Python.

I would like to attach the formula, but it doesn't seem to support picture uploading.

```
t=0:2*pi/99:2*pi;
st=sin(2*pi*t);
subplot(2,1,1);plot(st)
tao=0.1;
w=50;
syms t;
y=sin(t+tao/2).*conj(sin(t-tao/2)).*exp(-sqrt(-1)*w*t);
AF=int(y, t, -inf, inf);
subplot(2,1,2);plot(AF);
```

No graphics, no errors.

Comment: Are you sure there are no graphics generated? (There is when running your code in R2018a, 2018b and 2019a, and I can't see why there wouldn't be in previous releases.)  The first subplot contains a sine wave plotted on it.  The second part contains an empty axis because the integral is undefined (leading to `AF` being `NaN`) which is plotted as empty.  If AF was a symbolic function then you would plot it using `fplot` not `plot`.

Comment: Your `plot` command needs both `t` and `st`, i.e. `plot(t,st)`. Your second `plot` has no function to plot. The `int` command will get you a value, not an antiderivative function since integrating from negative infinity to positive infinity is considered an improper integral, which still gives you a finite number (or an undefined number... Either way, it won't get give you an antiderivative function)

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't make it clear, there is a sine wave and an empty axis there, but what I want to say is that the second subplot doesn't show the ambiguity image that I want. But I still don't know how to draw the integral from minus infinity to infinity.@Phil Goddard

Comment: You seem to be pointing out the key, and I realize that I'm drawing a definite integral.How am I supposed to draw the anti-derivatives?@KingDuken

Comment: I'm a rookie, and don't know where to put the formula. Anybody here?